# try-catch boilerplate in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exception, try-catch

I was wondering if there was a way in Laravel / PHP to reduce try-catch logic. For example, I have two methods in my controller:

**Store Method**

```
public function store(Request $request){
    try {

      $order = Order::create($request);

    } catch(\Exception $e) {

     return response()->json([
       "message" => 'An error has occured',
       "error" => $e->getMessage(),
     ], 500);

   }
}
```

**Update Method**

```
public function update(Request $request){
    try {

      $order = Order::update($request);

    } catch(\Exception $e) {

      return response()->json([
        "message" => 'An error has occured',
        "error" => $e->getMessage(),
      ], 500);

    }
 }
```

As one can see, the try-catch is identical in both cases, returning the same format of error.

Is there a way to extract this logic and wrap all controller methods in the same try-catch block?

Comment: You could route it through a single function which has a flag variable passed to it which selects what to run.

Comment: Make an exception response method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch and create your own response inside `render` method at `/app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Exception) {
        return response()->json([
          "message" => 'An error has occured',
          "error" => $exception->getMessage(),
        ], 500);
    }

    // or you might want to catch ModelNotFoundException
    // and give same response for all case
    else if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json([
          "message" => 'No model found. Please using valid ID',
          "error" => $exception->getMessage(),
        ], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Be careful, as this approach will affected all the same exceptions that being catch

Comment: Perfect! I could build a custom Exception class to target a smaller scope of exceptions.

Comment: Welcome mate. :)